# Can you use a Swiffer dry cloth to pickup fiberglass dust?

Tags: hvac, insulation, fiberglass

Had to rip out some internal duct insulation in the mechanical room and I want to clean up invisible and small leftover fiberglass fibers.  I also mistakenly used a shop vac initially so I'm afraid there might be some fiberglass dust left over.  It's not a huge area so I was thinking of using Swiffer dry static cloths to pick up stray fibers in the duct and around the ground, then follow up with a wet rag.

Would a Swiffer work in this case?  I see official guidelines say to avoid a broom because of stirring up dust, but it seems like a Swiffer dry cloth is made to pick up dust without disturbing.

Comment: Don’t have either so cannot test.

Comment: The only thing that really works is wet. Wet rag, wet mop.... I wouldn't use a dry swiffer but wet swiffer.